# Is the Splunk Universal Forwarder capable of sending data to FluentD

Tags: compatibility, splunk, fluentd

I have multiple Splunk Universal Forwarders, and I am looking to send them to an ETL tool. I am trying to evaluate whether FluentD is a compatible option for this.

FluentD has built in plug-ins for many specific log collection tools, however the Splunk UF is not listed as one of them. However, FluentD is capable of receiving traffic over HTTPS, and Splunk is capable of sending log data over HTTPS, does this mean the two are compatible?

Comment: As @RichG said, the Splunk Universal Forwarder is for sending data to *Splunk*. If you want to send it elsewhere, you need a different tool.

Comment: There are plenty of open source or far less expensive options which can ingest and perform ETL operations on data from Splunk UFs and, route said data to Splunk Indexers among other targets. I was wondering if FluentD is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Splunk's Universal Forwarder (UF) can send data using the Splunk-to-Splunk protocol or Splunk HTTP Event Collector (HEC) format.

Why not use Splunk instead of FluentD?  Or use Cribl instead of a UF to send to FluentD?

Comment: I am evaluating Cribl as well, however I want to understand whether Splunk UF is capable of sending data to FluentD both to understand how it works, and to understand if FluentD is a valid open source alternative to Cribl.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not compatible, even though the Universal forwarder sends data over HTTPS, the data is still using the S2S proprietary protocol, so even if you set FluentD up to receive the data, it wouldn't know what to do with it as it won't be able to decode it.